# phpspec tests within zend 2 module

Tags: zend-framework2, phpspec

I'm trying to move my spec folder into a zend 2 module folder. I don't totally understand how phpspec determines where the source folder is. How can I configure it to use the below folder structure.

```
\ModuleName
    \spec
        \ModuleName
            \Class.php
    \src
        \ModuleName
            ClassSpec.php
    ...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure spec and src paths, see the docs:
http://phpspec.net/en/latest/cookbook/configuration.html

If that doesn't solve your issue, you'll need to write a phpspec extension and provide a custom resource locator. Here's a similar example for Symfony: 
https://github.com/phpspec/Symfony2Extension/blob/master/src/PhpSpec/Symfony2Extension/Locator/PSR0Locator.php

Comment: To add this I had to add my namespace to the composer.json and run update. I was forgetting to run the update.  Thank you for you quick response!!

Comment: The url you mentioned does not exist anymore ... Plesae use : 
http://www.phpspec.net/en/latest/cookbook/configuration.html